# link to a specific tab by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I need your help!

I have a tab function by jquery in my site. and it works well.

Here is a javascript in < head >

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// When the document loads do everything inside here ...
$(document).ready(function(){
    // When a link is clicked
    $("a.tab").click(function () {
    // switch all tabs off
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    // switch this tab on
    $(this).addClass("active");
    // slide all content up
    $(".content").slideUp();
    // slide this content up
    var content_show = $(this).attr("title");
    $("#"+content_show).slideDown();
    });
});
</script>
```

and html sources are here!

```
<ul id="tabs">
    <li><a href="#" title="type1" class="tab active">type1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="type2" class="tab">type2</a></li>
</ul>
<section id="type1" class="content">
    <p>contents1contents1contents1contents1contents1</p>
</section>
<section id="type2" class="content content_2">
    <p>contents2contents2contents2contents2</p>
</section>
```

But i need to link a button to a specific tab.
there is the button in a category archive page, and when users click the button, the page opens with the contents in the second tab, id named "type2".

above sources are referred to by [this page](http://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/001_Tabbed/site/jQuery.html)
and here is [the page](http://hikarimoushikomi.com/east/ryoukin/flets-next/) that i'm working on.

i'm waiting for your advices!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your html file above is named index.html, you can create a link like:

```
<a href="index.html#!type2">click</a>
```

Then:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function doTab() {
        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".content").slideUp();
        var content_show = $(this).attr("title");
        $("#"+content_show).slideDown();
    }

    // When a link is clicked
    $("a.tab").click(doTab);

    if (window.location.hash) {
        $('a[title="' + window.location.hash.substring(2) + '"]').click();
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for advice!!! it works!!!
but when it opens the linked page, the position of page is not on top, but somwhere of the page.
i think it's affected by the position of section's id.

can you help me to fix it?

Comment: Updated. Don't forget to upvote and check the correct answer.

Comment: um...it doesn't work for me. 
this site is operated by wordpress. so i don't have a html page. 
and the section's ID is named in japanese. 
those things could make troubles?

here, i'll link [the page](http://hikarimoushikomi.com/east/ryoukin/). 
if you need to test, in the center of page, you can find small "test", and click it.

Comment: Here's a simpler approach, add a ! after the hash in the link so that it doesn't scroll to your tabs. Updated answer.

Comment: thank you!!! it works!!!! perfect!!!! unfortunately, i have only 8 reputation. when i get 7 reputation more, i'll up vote!! definitely!