# jQuery Tabs, link to specific tab from a different file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'm using Bootstrap 3 to create a simple site.
I've created on about.html some Tabs with different content.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="TabSomos">
<li class="active"><a href="#somos" data-toggle="tab">Quienes Somos</a></li>
<li><a href="#nosotros" data-toggle="tab">Nosotros</a></li>
<li><a href="#calidad" data-toggle="tab">Calidad</a></li>
</ul>

<article class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane active" id="somos">...</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="nosotros">...</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="calidad">...</div>
</article>
```

From index.html I want to create links that open different tabs. I created an ID per tab. However, since it's "hidden" it doesn't work properly.

```
<a href="nosotros.html#calidad">Modelos de Calidad</a>
```

I've been reading this solution: [link to a specific tab by jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10327310/link-to-a-specific-tab-by-jquery) however I do not fully understand where(and why) to put the scripts. Not sure if that's just within the same html document or between different ones, that it's the thing I need.

Any advice? (As you may see I'm not really that proficient with JS/jQuery). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand your question completely but here is what i can help you with what i understand.

You want to open a particular tab using the ID in about page.

Try using this code at the end of your about.html page,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var hash = location.hash;
   $(hash).tab('show');
});
```

Comment: Thank you, what I'm trying to do is:
Have the tabs at the aboutus.html file, and then on the footer of the other sections (index.html, contact.html, and so on) have some links to specific tabs.

Comment: You are using bootstrap right? Pass the ID of your tab link in your anchor tag on other sections. You can get the ID from the URL using `location.hash` For example Check the following link [http://jsfiddle.net/LZ2ar/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/LZ2ar/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you vigneshmoha,

It seems that someone asked the "same" question as well, and we were heading in the right direction regarding the hash.

[Bootstrap tabs opening tabs on another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163188/bootstrap-tabs-opening-tabs-on-another-page)